# Camera property in SpriteKit SKScene is always nil

Tags: ios, camera, sprite-kit, skscene

I'm trying to play a little bit around with the camera property of SKScene (iOS version)

I'm confused, it is always nil, even if I create a new instance and assign it:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The reference is weak so unless you have a strong ownership of it it will just be released.

In your sample by self.addChild() will hold a strong reference to local vairable.  Below would fix your problem:

```
Import SpriteKit
class GameScene:SKScene {

   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      var cameraNode = SKCameraNode()

      self.addChild(cameraNode)
      self.camera = cameraNode
      print(self.camera)


   }
```

}